# Facebook application story impressions

Tags: facebook, impressions

Do you know if when using Facebook ads which sponsor the stories posted by the application, these impressions count in the Insights statistics under "Story Impressions"

Answer (score 0):

It usually dependents on the number of news feed stories. This may cause different in the number of impressions you are receiving. 
Maybe you should try using a combination of Facebook Ads and Sponsored Stories to raise impressions.

Comment: Hi, yes I use Facebook Ads in order to raise impressions, which indirect goal is to get lower overall percentage of "Spam reports of 10k Impressions".

It worked for me when I needed it, before about 30 days, but it does not look to work right now.

Currently I get about 3000 impressions daily accounted as impressions from published stories from the application. 3-4 spam reports from these and the application would be gone..

I am buying right now from 3 days in a row about 400k impressions for the application published stories, and they do not count in the statistics :-(

Comment: After several days watching statistics, and tweaking - for example I did place a query string for the sponsored stories made by my application in order to track refferals.

Now I can confirm that Facebook Insights do not track all the impressions in the Stream Publish section.

Have any one noticed that and do you know where to send bug report?

Comment: I created a facebook app about 2 weeks ago. In my insights section it says this: 157,116 Story Impressions. What does this mean?